# Discord.py "message" is not defined error even though nothing is wrong?

Tags: python, discord.py

So I am pretty new to making Discord bots **and** python, however, whenever I try to run this it returns an error:
[image]
Here is my code:

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import keepAlive

keepAlive.awake("https://Shulker.E1ytra.repl.co", False)

TOKEN = os.environ['TOKEN']
intents = discord.Intents().all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  guild = await bot.fetch_guild(958309214663622697)
  role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='unverified')
  await member.add_roles(role)
  await bot.process_commands(message)
  

@bot.command()
async def verf(ctx, arg):
    if (arg == '51304'):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        member = ctx.author
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Basement People")
        await member.add_roles(role)
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="unverified")
        await member.remove_roles(role)
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title=" ", description=(ctx.message.author) + "Welcome to the server.", color=0x9b59b6)
        await ctx.send(embed=embedVar, delete_after=5)
    else:  
        await ctx.message.delete()
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title=" ", description=(ctx.message.author) + "The secret code is invalid.", color=0x9b59b6)
        await ctx.send(embed=embedVar, delete_after=5)


@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    if reason == None:
        reason = "N/A"
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.guild.kick(member)
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title=" ", description=f"{member.mention} has been kicked. Reason: {reason}", color=0x9b59b6)
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)


@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    if reason == None:
        reason = "N/A"
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.guild.ban(member)
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title=" ", description=f"{member.mention} has been banned. Reason: {reason}", color=0x9b59b6)
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)


@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def unban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    if reason == None:
        reason = "N/A"
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.guild.unban(member)
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title=" ", description=f"{member.mention} has been unbanned. Reason: {reason}", color=0x9b59b6)
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def lock(ctx, channel : discord.TextChannel=None):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    overwrite = ctx.channel.overwrites_for(ctx.guild.default_role)
    overwrite.send_messages = False
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, overwrite=overwrite)
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title=" ", description=f"<#{ctx.channel.id}> has been locked.", color=0x9b59b6)
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def unlock(ctx, channel : discord.TextChannel=None):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    overwrite = ctx.channel.overwrites_for(ctx.guild.default_role)
    overwrite.send_messages = True
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, overwrite=overwrite)
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title=" ", description=f"<#{ctx.channel.id}> has been unlocked.", color=0x9b59b6)
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

It did run earlier and did perform actions without any errors but I don't know what's wrong in here. It's getting really confusing. I do not know what to assign to "message" to make it normal. Is this just Replit or something's wrong with my code?

Again, I am stupid, don't kill me in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `description=(ctx.message.author) + "Welcome to the server."` python does not know how to get a string from the `User` (or `Member`) you get from the `author` field of `message` ([docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.author)).

What you probably want is `ctx.message.author.mention` which will give you a string that mentions the author or `author.display_name`.